# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classDirectories' for task '...' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just updated my Android Studio to 4.0 with a new version of Gradle, and I now have an error on my build.

`Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classDirectories' for task ':app:testNameOfMyFlavorDebugUnitTestCoverage' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.`

It's been working fine so far, I don't know what to change to make it work again.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Found the response here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#other_deprecated_behaviors_and_apis

And here : [Filter JaCoCo coverage reports with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887805/filter-jacoco-coverage-reports-with-gradle)

For example, `classDirectories` is replaced by `classDirectories.from`

Comment: where is this file located

Comment: That's a stupid non-backward compatible change made by gradle. I have one gradle version on the PC and another on my IDE. Looks like I'll have to match their versions now.

Answer (score 31):

You'll need to change from `classDirectories = SOME_DIRS` to `getClassDirectories().setFrom(SOME_DIRS)`.

Works OK with Gradle 6.1.1