# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'sourceDirectories' for org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport

Tags: android, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin

Using sourceDirectories and classDirectories for library `org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport`, I'm getting  A problem occurred evaluating project `:app`.

> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'sourceDirectories' for
> task ':app:generateCoverage' of type
> org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.

```
task generateCoverage(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {
    sourceDirectories = files('src/main/java')
    classDirectories = fileTree('build/intermediates/classes/debug') {
      
    }
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')
}
```

How to resolve this issue please suggest me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classDirectories' for task '...' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113575/cannot-set-the-value-of-read-only-property-classdirectories-for-task-of)